# Angular: How to debug injection error in unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, angular

I sometimes get an injection error in unit tests which looks like below and that gives me no idea which dependency exactly I should fix. I tried to play with providers I have in `TestBed.configureTestingModule` config but that didn't help. Anyone have ideas how I can proceed with investigating the issue?

```
✖ should create
  Chrome 57.0.2987 (Mac OS X 10.11.0)
Error
    at injectionError (webpack:///~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:1232:21 <- src/test.ts:1992:86) [angular]
    at noProviderError (webpack:///~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:1270:0 <- src/test.ts:2030:12) [angular]
    at ReflectiveInjector_.Array.concat.ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (webpack:///~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:2772:0 <- src/test.ts:3532:19) [angular]
    at ReflectiveInjector_.Array.concat.ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (webpack:///~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:2811:0 <- src/test.ts:3571:25) [angular]
    at ReflectiveInjector_.Array.concat.ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (webpack:///~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:2743:0 <- src/test.ts:3503:25) [angular]
    at ReflectiveInjector_.Array.concat.ReflectiveInjector_.get (webpack:///~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:2612:0 <- src/test.ts:3372:21) [angular]
    at DynamicTestModuleInjector.Array.concat.NgModuleInjector.get (webpack:///~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:3577:0 <- src/test.ts:4337:52) [angular]
    at resolveDep (webpack:///~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:10981:0 <- src/test.ts:11741:45) [angular]
    at createClass (webpack:///~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:10849:0 <- src/test.ts:11609:32) [angular]
    at createDirectiveInstance (webpack:///~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:10675:21 <- src/test.ts:11435:37) [angular]
    at createViewNodes (webpack:///~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:12024:33 <- src/test.ts:12784:49) [angular]
    at callViewAction (webpack:///~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:12394:0 <- src/test.ts:13154:13) [angular]
    at execComponentViewsAction (webpack:///~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:12333:0 <- src/test.ts:13093:13) [angular]
    at createViewNodes (webpack:///~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:12051:0 <- src/test.ts:12811:5) [angular]
```

I'm using: `angular: 4.0.0`
`ng-cli: 1.0.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found one possible way. The stack trace shows there is a `resolveDep` method which causes error:

```
at resolveDep (webpack:///~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:10982:0 <- src/test.ts:11742:45) [angular]
```

so I put a break point inside this method:

```
debugger;
return startView.root.ngModule.injector.get(depDef.token, notFoundValue);
```

and refreshed Karma browser page as described in docs: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/testing/#!#test-debugging

I could see then what dependencies are required checking `devDep` variable:
[image]

Comment: Good find! Now I really wonder why on earth the most vital information is not mentioned in the error message at all...

You can get the same information from the line in module.ngfactory.js:

Object.defineProperty(DynamicTestModuleInjector.prototype, '_SqliteProvider_67', { get: function() {
  var self = this;
  if ((self.__SqliteProvider_67 == null)) { (self.__SqliteProvider_67 = new jit_SqliteProvider49(self.parent.get(jit_SQLite50))); }
  return self.__SqliteProvider_67;
}});

I'm on Angular 4.0.2.